# How can i get this function to check for an empty field?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm wondering why the validateForm() function isn't working. I am trying to check if theres empty fields in the textarea tags in my form but it isn't working and just proceeds onto the addEntry.php page without performing the validateForm function. Here is my HTML and Javascript code :

```
<form id ="myForms" action="addEntry.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" name= "myForm" required>
  <section id="container">
      <h2>Add Blog</h2>
        <aside id = "title">
            <label for="text"> </label>
            <textarea id = "title" type="text" placeholder="Title" name="content"style="height:2em" name="fname"></textarea>
        </aside>
        <aside id = "content">
            <label for="content"> </label>
            <textarea id = "content" type="text" placeholder="Enter your text here..." name="content"style="height:12em" name="fname"></textarea>  
        </aside>
        <article id = "buttons"></article>
            <input id = "submit" type="submit" value = "Post" onclick = "validateForm()">
            <input class = "reset" type = "button" onclick = "myFunction()" value = "Clear"> <br>
    </section>
</form>
    
<script> 
    
function myFunction() {
  var r = confirm("Do you want to clear the blog entry?");
  if (r == true) {
  document.getElementById("myForms").reset();
  alert("The fields were cleared!");
  } else {
    alert("No fields were cleared!");
  }
}
    
function validateForm() {
  var x = document.getElementsByName["myForm"]["fname"].value;
  alert("test");
  event.validateForm()
  if (x == "" || x == null) {
    alert("Name must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: add `required=""` attribute to fields that user have to fill ,so form not be posted untill he put someText in them !

Answer (score 0):

1. action="addEntry.php":
   The form action will always send data to 'addEntry.php' - even if validation fails.  You should use `document.getElementById("myForm").submit();` once validation has completed successfully! Read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) about event.preventDefault() when using a button/input with type="submit".
2. textarea name:
   You have multiple textarea elements with two names - and they are the same name! (content, content, fname, fname)... Always use unique names.
3. textarea id:
   You have multiple elements that share the same ID! (title, title, content, content)... Always use unique IDs or reuse a class.
   With JS it is best to use ID `id="myTitleTextarea"` to select a unique element. With PHP you must use the `name="myContentTextarea"` to reference input (you used the POST method so - `$title =  $_POST['myContentTextarea'];`)
4. input type='submit':
   Inputs / buttons with the type of submit will always 'submit' the data to the 'action' of the form. This may prevent validation from ever occurring.
5. input class='reset' onclick='myFunction()':
   Any input or button with **type**='reset' will already reset the form - your function 'myFunction()' is not required (unless you want to prompt and make sure the user wants to reset)
6. validateForm() event:
   The function validateForm() was not passed an event... there is no need for event.validateForm() - also this would loop infinitely, if it worked.
7. validateForm() var x:
   Use more sensible names like `var fnameValue = ...`. When selecting elements with JS - it may be easier to use ID's instead of names - `getElementById('content')`
8. document.getElementsByName["myForm"]["fname"].value:
   TypeError: document.getElementsByName.myForm is undefined...

**Use the developer console when testing!!! Check out DevTools as this will notify and may explain any errors you encounter!**

**Chrome** https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/

**Firefox** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools